# filtering similar ids by their latest version

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a collection with id and version number properties. I want to filter this data so that only the latest record of each is shown.

```
    const data = [
        {
        id: 1,
        version: 1
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        version: 2
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        version: 3
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        version: 1
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        version: 1
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        version: 2
        }
    ];
```

After the filter it should be:

```
    const data = [
        {
        id: 1,
        version: 1
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        version: 1
        },

        {
        id: 3,
        version: 2
        }
    ];
```

What's the best way to do this filter with less complexity/Order? using lodash is allowed.

I was thinking to sort based on the version number, and pick all data with the greatest version number, then going to the next lower version and checking if it exists in the data then leaving it if not adding it, and so on until the version reaches 1. However, I am not sure if it's the best way and how I write it using lodash utils.

Comment: Why is the version of `id 1` is 1 while that of `id 3` is 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lodash, group by the `id`, then map and take the object with the maximum `version` from each group.

**Note**: `_.groupBy` converts the array to an object using the `id` as key, and since you're using integer ids, the order would change according to the `id`s numeric values. If that's a problem see the 2nd solution.

```js
const { map, groupBy, maxBy } = _

const data = [{"id":1,"version":1},{"id":1,"version":2},{"id":1,"version":3},{"id":2,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":2}]

const result = map(
  groupBy(data, 'id'),
  g => maxBy(g, 'version')
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Vanilla JS, reduce the the array to a Map. For each item check if it exists in Map, and if it doesn't or if it's version is greater than the one in the Map, set the current object for that `id`. Convert the Map's values back to array using `Array.from()`.

**Note**: using a Map preserves the original order of the array items.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"version":1},{"id":1,"version":2},{"id":1,"version":3},{"id":2,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":2}]

const result = Array.from(data.reduce((acc, o) =>
  acc.has(o.id) && acc.get(o.id).version >= o.version
    ? acc
    : acc.set(o.id, o)
, new Map()).values())

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach:

- Create an Object with key as ID and value as version.

  - This will automatically retain latest value for a given key-value pair
- Create a loop and create objects again

  - `{ id: key, version: value }`

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"version":1},{"id":1,"version":2},{"id":1,"version":3},{"id":2,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":1},{"id":3,"version":2}]

const map = data.reduce(
  (acc, {id, version}) => ({ ...acc, [id]: version}),
  {}
)
const result = Object.entries(map).map(([k, v]) => ({id: k, version: v}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems reasonably efficient:  sort by both ID and version in one pass, then you can just filter down to the last instance of each ID, because that'll be the one with the highest version number.  Of course, if your data comes pre-sorted, you can skip straight to the fun part; I reordered the source data here to show the sort working:

```js
const latestVersions = d => {
  // sort by ID and version:
  d = d.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.id === b.id) {
      return a.version - b.version
    } else {
      return a.id - b.id
    }
  }).filter((a, i) => {
    // only return elements that aren't followed by another with the same ID:
    return d[i + 1]?.id !== a.id
  })

  return d
}

const data = [{
    id: 1,
    version: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    version: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    version: 2
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    version: 1
  },

  {
    id: 1,
    version: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    version: 1
  }
];

console.log(latestVersions(data))
```

Comment: off topic: you can `.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id || a.version - b.version)`

Comment: True!  I think it's a little harder to read that way, but that absolutely does work.